# event delegation with jQuery 1.3.2

Tags: jquery, event-delegation

I'm stuck using jQuery 1.3.2 at the moment and I'm just beginning to understand event delegation in general.  But I can't seem to get any sort of event delegation to work on this code. I have a ul with a class 'chat' which when hovering over one of it's li's should create a new span which then slides out, then slides back in when the mouse leaves the li.

This code works, but I want to use event delegation:

```
$('ul.chat li').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).append($('<span class="join">Join Conversation</span>'));
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.join').animate({'width': '150px'}, 400);
        },500);
    },
    function() {
        $('.join').animate({'width': '0px'}, 200, function(){
            $(this).remove();                                             
        }); 
    }
);
```

Can someone show me how to achieve the same result, but with event delegation?
Thanks.

Comment: `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` don't support bubbling/delegation.  `jQuery.live` didn't support `hover` in 1.3, until they put in a workaround in 1.4 (I think they just use `mouseover` and `mouseout`)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Doesn't seem like you want event delegation for added items, but more because you'll be working with a very large result set.

A quick search on Google ('event delegation jquery 1.3.2') came up with [this](http://www.clickoffline.com/2009/04/optimized-event-delegation-in-jquery/).

---

You can get "event delegation" with the [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event.

You'll have to split that into two bindings, like so:

```
$('ul.chat li').live('mouseover',
    function() {
        $(this).append($('<span class="join">Join Conversation</span>'));
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.join').animate({'width': '150px'}, 400);
        },500);
    }
).live('mouseout',
    function() {
        $('.join').animate({'width': '0px'}, 200, function(){
            $(this).remove();                                             
        }); 
    }
);
```

Comment: In jQuery 1.3.2, `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` aren't supported for `live`; they need to be substituted with `mouseover` and `mouseout` (http://api.jquery.com/live/#caveats)

Comment: Ah. I wasn't sure, so I just used whichever the docs said `jQuery.hover()` was shorthand for. Will update in a sec. Thanks! =)

Comment: My main concern is reducing the number of bindings that occur (i think I'm saying that correctly). I was told by a senior programmer that the events are being bound to every li, even when they don't need to be, when it could be bound only to the ul.chat.  He said I should look into event delegation.

Does .live() make this happen?  Or does it just allow the hover stuff to happen on newly ajax injected list items?

Comment: I don't think that `live()` will reduce the number of bindings. I remember trying to do "traditional" delegation within jQuery bindings and finding that I couldn't emulate that functionality. What's the reason for wanting to reduce the number of bindings? Is your site/app running slowly, or are you worried it might start to slow down, or...?

Comment: Speed concerns.  I know it can be done, because this other guy does it with his team, but I just met this guy somewhere random and so can't ask him to go into detail.

Comment: I don't think that helps because it's still looking at every li rather than just one ul.

Comment: In the article I linked with my latest update, they put the event on the `table`, and then if the actual target was a `td` (and in this case had a class of `nameCell`) they run their event on it as planned.

Comment: Sorry, my eyes were stuck on the original code answer and I just saw your link.  That's what I was looking for.  Thanks!